# Case statement with aggregate and like clause - MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm really struggling with a case statement in MSSQL 2012. I've looked around for other answers, but although I've got some help, none seem to fix the problem.

```
case firstname
    when len(ltrim(rtrim(firstname))) > 11 then 'blah'
    else 'blahblah'
end as test
```

I am getting a syntax error, on the '>' character.

Originally, this was

```
case firstname
    when ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) like '% %' then 'blah'
    else 'blahblah'
end as test
```

but I thought there may have been some sensitivity on the like keyword, so I changed it to '>', but I get the same thing.

Probably a dumb question, but I've been banging my head for a couple of hours and some insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version:

```
(case when len(ltrim(rtrim(firstname))) > 11 then 'blah'
      else 'blahblah'
 end) as test
```

The `case` statement has two versions.  The one with the variable is used for constant expressions:

```
(case firstname
      when 'Arnold' then . . .
      when 'Betty' then . . .
 end)
```

The second version (which is really the only one I use) takes a conditional for each part:

```
(case when firstname = 'Arnold' then . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Chnage it to

```
case 
    when len(ltrim(rtrim(firstname))) > 11 then 'blah'
    else 'blahblah'
end as test
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the two forms of [`CASE` expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

A simple case expression checks each `WHEN` clause for equality with the expression after `CASE` and before the first `WHEN`.

A searched case expression checks separate arbitrary predicates in each `WHEN` clause and doesn't have an expression between `CASE` and the first `WHEN`.

Try:

```
case
    when len(ltrim(rtrim(firstname))) > 11 then 'blah'
    else 'blahblah'
end as test
```